# How to order woocommerce upsell products by name?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I find something after I ask this question in up-sell.php (in code below) if I changed second $orderby to anything up-sell items get in order by name but in reverse. For example they get in order like "product 2" then "product 1". So I need to reverse this code somehow. Thanks again.

```
$meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'no_found_rows'       => 1,
    'posts_per_page'      => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'             => $orderby,
    'post__in'            => $upsells,
    'post__not_in'        => array( $product->id ),
    'meta_query'          => $meta_query
);
```

Hi I put upsell product for every product in Wordpress Woocommerce but upsell products displayed in random order. I want to order them in name like "product 1" and then "product 2" etc... I couldn't find something that does this in google does anybody done this before? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'no_found_rows'       => 1,
    'posts_per_page'      => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'             => menu_order,
    'post__in'            => $upsells,
    'post__not_in'        => array( $product->id ),
    'meta_query'          => $meta_query
);
```

I changed $orderby to menu_order and it worked. I hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

This only worked for me when I added 'order' => asc:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'           => 'product',
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
'no_found_rows'       => 1,
'posts_per_page'      => $posts_per_page,
'orderby'             => menu_order,
'order'               => asc,
'post__in'            => $upsells,
'post__not_in'        => array( $product->id ),
'meta_query'          => WC()->query->get_meta_query()
);
```

Without that line I was still getting the products in reverse name order.